# pxe boot works but USB ports don't

Tags: usb, boot-issues, peripherals

I'm running a PXE server that provide the boot files perfectly.

The raspbian jessie start well but the mouse and keyboard doesn't work.

to create the respo, i've done a rsync on a working image mounting dev, sys and proc, regenerate ssh. Ziping it and put it on the server. deleting fstab p1 and p2.

when I run lsusb, I can see the mouse and the keyboard. If I remove them, they disapear.

best regards,
Thana

Comment: Try using Raspbian Stretch with the 4.14.79 kernel.

Comment: What's the question? How to make USB ports working on a netbooted root filesystem? Maybe it is just a problem of cloning the image and has nothing to do with netbooting.

Comment: @Dougie Yeah you were right. I was using a september update and with the november it works perfectly. Can you explain why ? (getting the response is good but knowing why I failled is better).
Ingo : it's not a cloning trouble, I've done the exact same  process now and it works fine.
thanks for helping me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In all cases your Raspberry Pi needs firmware, bootcode and a kernel that includes support for your hardware. The easiest way to get that is with the 2018-11-13 (current version) Raspbian Stretch or Raspbian Stretch Lite.

If your hardware is newer than your firmware/bootcode/kernel you may find that re-designed hardware components don't run.

Upgrading to 4.14.79 (current stable kernel) should resolve most of these types of anomaly.

Comment: ok I i've update the internal kernel, I must use the last one, no easy way to go back. Thank you very much